# Custom session state provider needed for DB storage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, session-state, asp.net-4.0

I know this question is related to many others, but please bear with me.

I am trying an experiment to store all information in database tables instead of the ASP.NET session.  In ASP.NET 4 one can create a custom provider for session.  So, again should I implement a Custom Session-State Provider or should I just disable session (in Web.config)?

Thanks!

From the comments my question can be misunderstood.  Hopefully this tidbit will help clarify:

I don't want to store the session in the database. I want to store information in the database that you would typically store in the session. One reason why: I don't want to carry around a session on every page, especially if that page doesn't care about 90 percent of the information in the session

Comment: You can just configure SessionState to work with SQL Server to store session information. Why would you need a provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of reinventing the wheel there is already a [built-in SQL provider](http://idunno.org/articles/277.aspx) which you could use out of the box and which will store session data into SQL Server allowing for you application to better scale in web farm environments:

```
<sessionState
  mode="SQLServer"
  sqlConnectionString="data source=server;user id=uid;password=pwd"
  cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
```

Comment: I want to avoid the performance issues inherent with session, including SQL Server Session State mode.

Comment: @subt13, if you want to avoid it why are you asking how to store ASP.NET session in SQL tables? The built-in SQL State session provider is very optimized and reliable and I would strongly advice you against reimplementing your own.

Comment: @subt12, ohhh yes. I totally misunderstood it then :-) Well in this case simply disable the session with `<sessionState mode="Off" />`. That would be the best in terms of performance and scalability.

Comment: Cool that's what I was hoping :)  By the way, have you heard any success stories by doing (or not doing in this case) session this way?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: The only problem is that the built-in session provider is not flexible enough.